# Trouble with parsing xml file that has an empty element

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am trying to parse an xml file using ElementTree.parse but I'm getting a mismatched tag error when there is an empty element.

The xml file I am provided with writes empty elements with the end tag only.

```
<person>
     <name>Mike</name>
     </age>
</person>
```

Everytime I use ElementTree.parse() on files like this, I get a mismatched tag error, because the "age" element is empty, so it only prints the end tag. Is there any other way to parse an XML file if my file is like this?

Answer (score 2):

That is invalid XML. `</age>` is just the closing tag for the element, which has no opening tag.

A valid, empty `age` element would be written as `<age></age>` or, in the shortest possible version, `<age/>`.

You'll find out that `ElementTree.parse()` works correctly for the following document:

```xml
<person>
    <name>Mike</name>
    <age/>
</person>
```

See: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags